# Error in filtering sample in Shiny

Tags: r, filter, datatables, shiny, dplyr

.I have a dataframe consist of 100 samples. There are three column, one url link, second a name or a heading to the url link and third date. I want to display all those headings in shiny interface. Clicking which leads the user to the respective link page.
Filter samples through selected date. But I am getting a error

**Error in UseMethod: no applicable method for 'filter_' applied to an object of class "c('datatables', 'htmlwidget')" Please help**

**Below is the code**

```
    df$link <- paste0("<a href='", df$url, "' target='_blank'>", df$heading, "</a>")

ui <- fluidPage( dateRangeInput('dateRange',
                                label = 'Filter news by date',
                                start = as.Date('2001-01-01') , end = as.Date('2018-06-01')),
  DT::dataTableOutput("table")
   )

server <- function(input, output) {

  output$table <- DT::renderDataTable({
    DT::datatable(df[, c("link", "Date"), drop = FALSE], escape = FALSE) %>%
     dplyr::filter(df$Date >= input$dateRange[1] & df$Date <= input$dateRange[2])
  })

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are piping the result from `DT::datable` to `filter`, which is not a data frame-like object.

You probably want to apply `filter` to the data frame and then pass the result to `datatable` like this:

```
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$table <- DT::renderDataTable({
    DT::datatable(
      df[, c("link", "Date"), drop = FALSE] %>%
        dplyr::filter(df$Date >= input$dateRange[1] & df$Date <= input$dateRange[2]),
      escape = FALSE
    )
  })
}
```